# Wordpress multisite wp_upload_dir wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, url, upload, multisite

currently i'm trying to upload a Image to a Wordpress-Multisite at server side.
(The image is already on another path at the same server)

I've written a small PHP-script which should handle this:

```
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    var_dump( $upload_dir); 
    $filename = basename($imagepath);

    if (wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])) {
        $file = $upload_dir['path'].'/'.$filename;
    } else {
        $file = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.$filename;
    }

    copy($imagepath, $file);
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null);
    $attachment = array(
                    'guid' => $upload_dir['url'].'/'.basename($filename),
                    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_status' => 'inherit', );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $postid);
```

Everything works fine, but the image is stored in the wrong folder. 
`wp_upload_dir();` returns the common path `/wp-content/uploads/2016/03`, not the path for the specific subsite, wich will be `/wp-content/uploads/sites/SITE_ID/2016/03`

Later when WP uses the image, the url of the image is set to `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/SITE_ID/2016/03/IMAGE.JPG` (which is not correct...)

Uploading a file with the built-in media-upload tool from wordpress works correct (files are stored in `/wp-content/uploads/sites/SITE_ID/2016/03`)

You see, `wp_upload_dir()` is not working correct..

Thanks..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i solved it!

For everyone with the same problem, the solution is simple:

1. When you're on multisite, register a filter for "upload_dir"
2. define a function, where you change temporarily the paths and urls
3. That's it!

   ```
   if(is_multisite()){
       add_filter('upload_dir', 'fix_upload_paths');
   }

   function fix_upload_paths($data)
   {
       $data['basedir'] = $data['basedir'].'/sites/'.get_current_blog_id();
       $data['path'] = $data['basedir'].$data['subdir'];
       $data['baseurl'] = $data['baseurl'].'/sites/'.get_current_blog_id();
       $data['url'] = $data['baseurl'].$data['subdir'];

       return $data;
   }
   ```

Hope someone can use it. Hours of hours for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method is to use the `switch_to_blog()` function

```php
if( is_multisite() ) {
    switch_to_blog( get_current_blog_id() );
      $imgdir = wp_upload_dir();
      // do more process related to current blog
    // close the swicth
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

See details at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/